How do I make my mean calculations not return Nan on numeric data, using pandas package in python?
So I'm learning how to use pandas and I'm trying to group a df based on a set of parameters in one of the columns and perform the mean on another column.
The original df is this:
> df.head()




USAF
YR--MODAHRMN
TEMP
MAX
MIN
Celsius




28450
201705010000
31.0
NaN
NaN
-1.0


28450
201705010020
30.0
NaN
NaN
-1.0


28450
201705010050
30.0
NaN
NaN
-1.0


28450
201705010100
31.0
NaN
NaN
-1.0


28450
201705010120
30.0
NaN
NaN
-1.0



df.types

USAF              int64
YR--MODAHRMN      int64
TEMP            float64
MAX             float64
MIN             float64
Celsius         float64
The objetive is to convert the column YR--MODAHRMN into a string cut the portion that is of no interest and use the resulting column to group the data in order to calculate the mean of Celsius based on that grouping.
df["YR--MODAHRMN"]=df["YR--MODAHRMN"].astype(str)
df["YR--MODA"]=df["YR--MODAHRMN"].str[0:8]
df.head()
df.dtypes

USAF    YR--MODAHRMN    TEMP    MAX MIN Celsius YR--MODA

0   28450   201705010000    31.0    NaN NaN -1.0    20170501
1   28450   201705010020    30.0    NaN NaN -1.0    20170501
2   28450   201705010050    30.0    NaN NaN -1.0    20170501
3   28450   201705010100    31.0    NaN NaN -1.0    20170501
4   28450   201705010120    30.0    NaN NaN -1.0    20170501
df = df[["USAF","YR--MODA","Celsius"]]
df["MeanC"] = df["Celsius"].groupby(df["YR--MODA"]).mean(numeric_only=True)
df.dtypes
df.head()

|||
|----|----|
|USAF|int64|
|YR--MODA|object|
|Celsius|float64|
|MeanC|float64|
dtype: object



USAF
YR--MODA
Celsius
MeanC




28450
20170501
-1.0
NaN


28450
20170501
-1.0
NaN


28450
20170501
-1.0
NaN


28450
20170501
-1.0
NaN


28450
20170501
-1.0
NaN



All of the results are NaN eventhough the inputed data is numeric I'v ran pd.isnull(df)and it returned false on the Celsius column. What am I doing wrong?

IIUC: df['MeanC'] = df.groupby(df['YR--MODAHRMN'].str[0:8])['Celcius'].transform('mean')
